# Cypress: How can I solve error: Timed out retrying: cy.select() failed because this element: is being covered by another element:?

Tags: select, cypress

Every time when the command starts executing, page scroll down so the required element is not visible and it's hidden under the menu on the page and there is an error message *Timed out retrying: cy.select() failed because this element:  is being covered by another element:*.
That command looks just like this 
`cy.get('select').select('2')`.
So can anyone help me how to solve this error? I tried to use commands `.scrollTo()` or `.scrollIntoView()` but it didn't help either.

Comment: Scroll doesn't matter - object does not have to be in the current viewport to `get` it. Can you provide the object code? And there was an issue with selects, what version of chrome are you using?

Comment: Try to include { force: true } and see if it works. `cy.get('select').select('2', {force: true})`

Comment: `<select name="prezkoumavat" onchange="javascript:nastav_focus(name, form);" class="valid">
    <option value="1" selected="selected">přezkoumává se</option>
    <option value="2">nepřezkoumává se</option>
    <option value="3">nepřihlíží se</option>
    <option value="4">vyloučeno z uspokojení</option>
        <option value="5">odmítnuto</option>
</select>`  I'm using version 81.0.4044.138

Comment: In documentation of `.select()` is written: However, passing { force: true } to .select() will not override the actionability checks for selecting a disabled <select>, a disabled <option>, or an option within a disabled <optgroup>.

Comment: https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/03/20/working-with-select-elements-and-select2-widgets-in-cypress/ here shows a similar example of the error you mentioned. If the `select` has a wrapper pluggin (like select2) , that may cause this problem.